# WebLogic server losing session between Ajax calls

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, session, weblogic

I have a web app that runs perfectly on Apache Tomcat.  However, when I deploy it to WebLogic 10.2.3 server, it gets a NPE due to the session being null.

The app is Java 5, jQuery 1.7.1 running on Win 7 Pro. The first Ajax GET to the server causes some values to be stored in the session object.  The next Ajax GET uses these values - thus the NPE due to null session.

In Firebug, I see that different session IDs are being passed - why?

Can anyone help me resolve this?
[image]

Another piece of information.  Here's some related jQuery:

```
    $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
     },
     crossDomain: true
});
```

and:

```
    $('#findSites').click(function() {                                // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
    searchVal = document.getElementById("searchFor").value;
    searchTyp = document.getElementById("searchType").value;
    $.get('SiteSearchServlet', {searchFor: searchVal, searchType: searchTyp}, function(responseJson) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response JSON...
...
```

Comment: On WebLogic 10.3, if you add the following excerpt to weblogic.xml, it works:
    <session-descriptor>
    <cookie-http-only>false</cookie-http-only>
    </session-descriptor>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I got the same error.

Comment: Have your tried using .ajax instead of .get?

Comment: I thought GET just calls ajax... and did the ajaxsetup - what specifically do you think are option(s) in ajax to fix this?  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that adding this to the document ready function solved the problem (i.e. now I use the same session unless timeout):

```
    jQuery.support.cors = true; // force cross-site scripting
```

Hope this helps someone else.
Mark